# Check if socket is connected in compact framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, compact-framework, tcpclient

I have a server software running on windows desktop and developed in .net that is always listening for incoming connection on sockets through TCP/IP.

Then I have a client software running on CE 6.0 developed with compact framework 3.5...This client need to:

- Connect to the server when service is enabled
- Send few bytes of data every 300 ms
- Never hang while sending or lose time connecting every time
- Check if socket is connected

So far I implemented the server side with an Async code based on this sample but modified to keep connections alive until server close them...not only for one shot and it's perfectly working

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

then I implemented the client side this way:

```
dim clientSocket as new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()

/... code .../

'Activate the service
clientSocket.Connect("10.0.0.34", myPort)

/ .... code ..../ 

'Data send function
dim serverStream as NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
dim outStream as byte() = System.Text.Enconding.ASCII.GetBytes("My messagge...")
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
serverStream.Flush
```

Also this is perfectly working. What do I need?

1. To detect if connection with socket is open before send data...this will avoid loss of time in case something went wrong

I searched among the web but I couldn't do a way to do it in CF...and the .connected method is not available here.

The best - but it seems stupid to me - way I found is to set a flag when connection/send is successful and to reset it when something goes wrong.

Comment: FYI, a NetworkStream does not cache writes so Flush doesn't do anything for you.  See here for details:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I once experimented with polling my sockets for determining if they are still connected or not. But according to my experience the only reliable, device independent way to determinate if a socket is already closed or not is that a send operation succeeds or times out on it. (Note: you might want to check that timeout yourself. While standard TCP sockets time out after 20 seconds if I remember well, I've seen some non-standard ones before that just didn't want to time out for minutes.) If you are lucky then you have "ping" mechanism in the protocol you are implementing over the socket so you can run some meaningless data over the network from time to time just to see if you still have the connection. I know, it can create quite an overhead, but if you really need to know, this is the only way that works on absolutely every device.